# iwlwifi: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110 in Arch Linux kernel version 5.5.3

Tags: arch-linux, kernel-modules, intel, iwlwifi

I'm new to Arch Linux. I installed it on my laptop(LG Gram)
it seem fine post installation. I don't remember my wlan works post installation because I used wired. But, when I turned on my laptop today wlan interface load fails. I lastly installed wine 5.1 yesterday but I don't think is the reason. I searched other cases in google but I couldn't find any valid solutions. How can I fix my driver?

```
❯ lspci -kvnn | sed -n '/Network/,/^$/ p'
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0034]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at a2618000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

```
❯ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    2.746905] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.756780] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.756783] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.757082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.ceaaecdc.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.053411] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    3.060880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.061363] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    8.178291] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    8.178298] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    8.178301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    8.178445] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 9df08086 00100406 02800030 00800000 a2618004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178450] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00348086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[    8.178453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000040: 00928010 10000ec0 00100c10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000405 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178461] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000080: 800f0011 00002000 00003000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178465] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178469] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000008 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178472] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000100: 14c00000 ff000000 000000ff 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178479] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178483] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 16410018 00000000 0001001e 00481e1f 00000000
[    8.178486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    8.178510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 18c89008 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.178514] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000010 0c000005 00000312 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0042
[    8.178523] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[    8.178535] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    8.178540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    8.428342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    8.428350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    8.428352] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6EFC0A0E | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    8.428354] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    8.428356] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7DC9CAA6 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    8.428358] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    8.428360] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA51C1518 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    8.428362] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC08AE419 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    8.428364] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF6FC466C | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    8.428365] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB1E04F68 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    8.428367] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.428371] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.428376] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    8.428410] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    8.428413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    8.428582] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[    8.441398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

I found someone [similar issue](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243691) with me but his solution is not working for me.
I added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet intel_iommu=off"` and grub-mkconfig again but it didn't work.

My Network Interface is not even loaded so I can't do something like `iwconfig wlan0 power off`

```
❯ ifconfig -a
enp0s20f0u3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.28  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::5f9b:8d19:a256:b280  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:e0:4c:f1:54:e9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10320  bytes 6390510 (6.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9090  bytes 1341283 (1.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16  bytes 960 (960.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 960 (960.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I searched some info in google and tried but there was no valid solution.

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going on but it fixed after few reboot. I really to find solution and tried everything I found. It seem not worked at all. I found driver for my wlan and put in to /lib/firmware and rebooted. Now it works. After installing arch linux my wlan worked well but maybe something went wrong when installing softwares. Cheers

Comment: The error messages would seem to indicate a failure to load a firmware file to the WiFi chip. Those chips are essentially tiny computers of their own - it seems the chip "crashed" and required a power off/on cycle to restart. Without programming documentation for that specific chip, it's hard to say anything more specific than that.